# How To Update One Table from Another Using Razor Page App (Non-MVC)

Tags: database, razor, razor-pages

I'm looking for a basic understanding (or location of a good tutorial) on how to update one table based on a change to another table.

For example, I have a model Agency, that is like this:

```
namespace XYZ.Model
{
    public class Agency
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Agency")]
        public string AgencyName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Added/Updated By")]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Added/Updated")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have another Incident model that uses the AgencyName field in a dropdown on Create and Edit pages called ArrestDept. Abbreviated model shown below.

```
namespace XYZ.Model
{
    public class Incident
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Case Type")]
        ...
        [Display(Name = "Arresting Dept")]
        public string? ArrestDept { get; set; }
        ...
    }

}
```

Let's say that when I am entering an AgencyName on the CreateModel page for the Agency model, that I spell the AgencyName wrong. Instead of XYZ Agency, I mistakenly put ZYX Agency. Then, that mispelled name gets used on some records created using the ArrestDept dropdown on the  CreateModel page for the Incident model.

I can go in and correct the Agency Model spelling on the EditModel page for the Agency Model, but how do I get that change to carry over to the records in the Incident model that were selected with the INCORRECT SPELLING?

Hope I am explaining well? Is there a change I have to make to the Agency EditModel.cs page to also update the Incident Model data?

Thanks very much for any assistance you can provide. Basic razor tutorials I have been watching cover creating individual models and pages, but not updating one from another.

Answer (score 0):

You make `Agency` a property of `Incident`, which translates to a foreign key in the Incident table that maps to the Agency table:

```
public class Incident
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Case Type")]
    public int AgencyId { get; set; } 
    public Agency Agency { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Arresting Dept")]
    public string? ArrestDept { get; set; }
}
```

In your Incident form, present a dropdown containing all the agencies in your database so that the user can pick one.

Relationships between entities is covered in this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I am getting an error doing this. ERROR: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Incident_Agency_AgencyId". The conflict occurred in database "XYZ", table "dbo.Agency", column 'Id'. Is this because in the Agency model  that the Id is simply named 'Id' and needs to be named 'AgencyId' the same as the FK in the Incident model? It looks like that could be the issue when I view the tutorial link you gave me, but wanted to check. Thanks!